# how does .isNumber work in underscore.js?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

In underscore.js, the following code seems to add _.isNumber()

```
  // Add some isType methods: isArguments, isFunction, isString, isNumber, isDate, isRegExp.
  each(['Arguments', 'Function', 'String', 'Number', 'Date', 'RegExp'], function(name) {
    _['is' + name] = function(obj) {
      return toString.call(obj) == '[object ' + name + ']';
    };
  });
```

but there must be something else going on, because copying this code straight into firefox causes it to fail as `toString.call(5)` returns `[xpconnect wrapped native prototype]` -- so its obviously doing something else somewhere - but I can't figure out what.

Here's an example of the results in firefox:

http://jsbin.com/uviyaz/2/edit

Comment: I tested `Object.prototype.toString.call(5)` and I get `"[object Number]"` in Firefox.

Comment: `--
[18:36:42.386] ({}).toString.call(5)
[18:36:42.388] "[object Number]"` works fine

Comment: to both commenters -- yes, but the format in underscore.js is as above, and in firefox it returns that gibberish string, as per jsbin example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your jsbin is showing `window.toString`, where as underscore is using `Object.prototype.toString`, they have aliased it to `toString` locally in their code.

See http://jsbin.com/uviyaz/3/edit

See also [underscore's source](http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js) where they do it:

```
  // Create quick reference variables for speed access to core prototypes.
  var slice            = ArrayProto.slice,
      unshift          = ArrayProto.unshift,
      toString         = ObjProto.toString,
      hasOwnProperty   = ObjProto.hasOwnProperty;
```

Comment: ah now that makes sense -- I hadn't realized they had modified toString.

Comment: @Will they haven't they are using local `toString`. Local variables shadow global variables so the global `window.toString` is shadowed and not therefore used.

Comment: Btw, the real "owner" of the `window.toString` function is the `Window.prototype` object (at least in non-IE browsers). So, the recommended name would be `Window.prototype.toString`. (This is to avoid confusion, as someone might think that that function is defined on the `window` object itself.)

Comment: @ŠimeVidas true but it doesn't really matter here :P (or anywhere since one cannot rely on it anyway)

Comment: @Esailija Avoiding confusion *always* matters `:P`

Comment: Well it's not right to say that it belongs to prototype, it doesn't in IE (`({}).hasOwnProperty.call( window, "toString") //true`) and it's a host object where this kind of thing is not specified because the specs specify interfaces.

Comment: It's worse than I thought. The *Window* interface is implemented as a `Window` global constructor (and presumably, a native ECMAScript object) in Firefox, Chrome, and IE9/8. However, such a global constructor does not exist in Safari and Opera, which disappoints me. (Btw, it *does* belong to the prototype in IE9. IE8, however, for some reason defines two separate `window.toString` and `Window.prototype.toString` functions.)

Comment: So, to sum up, `window.toString === Window.prototype.toString` is true in Firefox, Chrome, and IE9. Since the general direction appears to be to implement the browser object model (including the DOM) as native ECMAScript objects, what Safari/Opera are waiting for, is beyond me.

Comment: The dom specification doesn't require browsers to implement them as native ecmascript objects though it's of course preferable

Answer (score 0):

In underscore's code, `toString` is a local variable which value is `Object.prototype.toString`. You assumed that it's a global function - that's why you got unexpected results.

From [underscore's source code](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L23):

```
  // Save bytes in the minified (but not gzipped) version:
  var ArrayProto = Array.prototype,
      ObjProto = Object.prototype,
      FuncProto = Function.prototype;

  // Create quick reference variables for speed access to core prototypes.
  var push = ArrayProto.push,
      slice = ArrayProto.slice,
      unshift = ArrayProto.unshift,
      toString = ObjProto.toString,
      hasOwnProperty = ObjProto.hasOwnProperty;
```